# Why onSubmit doesnt submit form when i pass it in the form element. But it does submit when I pass it in the button element in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, crud

I have a question. Im writing in React btw. So when I pass in the onSubmit handler in the form element, it doesnt submit the form when I click "add todo". However when I pass the handler into the button element, it does submit the form? Please see below for code. I have included the child component file that is nested in the form just in case:

```
// TodoForm,js
import React from "react";
import PrioritySelector from "./PrioritySelector";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class TodoForm extends React.Component {


    state = {
        priorityLevel: null
    }

    /*submit handler to grab input from the input references and store them
    in the "todoData" object. Then dispatches an action type and payload
    capturing the data. Then clears the input*/
    handleSubmit=( e )=> {
       e.preventDefault()
        const todoTitle = this.getTodoTitle.value;
        const description = this.getDescription.value;
        const priorityLevel = this.state.priorityLevel;
        const todoData = {
            id: Math.floor(Math.random()*1000),
            todoTitle,
            description,
            priorityLevel,
            editing: false
        }
        this.props.dispatch({type:"ADD_TODO", todoData })
        this.getTodoTitle.value = "";
        this.getDescription.value = "";

    }


    getData=(priorityLevels)=> {
        const data = priorityLevels;
        this.setState({
            priorityLevel: data
        })
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" ref={(input)=> this.getTodoTitle=input} placeholder="Enter Todo" required/>
                    <input type="text" ref={(input)=> this.getDescription=input} placeholder="Enter Description" required/>
                    <PrioritySelector getData={this.getData} />
                    <button onClick={this.handleSubmit} type="button">Add Todo</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default connect()(TodoForm);



// PrioritySelecter.js
import React from "react";
import $ from "jquery";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class PrioritySelector extends React.Component  {


    componentDidMount() {
        $("#selector").show();
    }

    handleSelect =(e)=> {
       const priorityLevel = this.getPriorityLevel.value;
       this.props.getData(priorityLevel);
       console.log(priorityLevel)
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <div className="input-field col s12">
                    <select onChange={this.handleSelect} ref={(option)=> this.getPriorityLevel = option} id="selector">
                        <option disabled defaultValue>Choose your option</option>
                        <option value="1">Low</option>
                        <option value="2">Medium</option>
                        <option value="3">High</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

}


const mapStateToProps=(state)=> {
    return {
        priorityLevel: state
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrioritySelector);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button is type="button" so it will not submit the form. 
Change it to type="submit" and put the handler on the form.

Comment: Thanks! That was it